# How to add alphanumerics in excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am maintaining stock of flavors in a row:

```
Cell B1 : 5vanilla,5cola,5mango
```

Similarly

```
Cell C1 : 3vanilla,3cola,3mango
```

Is there a sum formula with which I can get
auto sum in Cell F1 as `8vanilla,8cola,8mango`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're putting this information into one cell, instead of a column for `Flavour` and another column for `Quantity`?

Comment: yeah.
the whole sheet is for stock maintenance and flavors is only one of it. 
Also there are about 15 flavors and i have to maintain them for a month.
i don't want to have a separate sheet for it.
Is there a formula for what i want?

Comment: There isn't a way using standard Excel formulas - you could create a UDF to do it though.

Comment: Do B1 and C1 always contain the same three flavors in the same order, and only the quantities change?  Do you know in advance what those are?  Can the quantities in B1 and C1 exceed 9?

Answer (score 0):

**A Draft to Start With**

It is not recommended to mix texts and numbers. But here is the solution if you insist:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(B1,1))+NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(C1,1))
```

Replace `B1`, `C1` with cell references and `1` with digits before word (e.g. 1mango: 1 digit, 12cola: 2 digits).

This function is auto-fill friendly and you can use auto-fill as long as your data format is consistent.

[image: Excel Demo]

Edit: Edited function to work on the question.

**Version 2**

```
=(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,1))+NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(B1,1)))&"abc,"&(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH(",",A1)+1,1))+NUMBERVALUE(MID(B1,SEARCH(",",B1)+1,1)))&"bcd"
```

[image: Excel Demo 2]

This function searches for `,` and picks the next character (number), you can expand it and include/replace the product name and inventory digits for your data.

**Version 3**

EXTREMELY LONG FORMULA WARNING:

```
=( NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,1))+NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(B1,1)) )&"product1,"&( NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH(",",A1)+1,1))+NUMBERVALUE(MID(B1,SEARCH(",",B1)+1,1)) )&"product2,"&( NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH(",",A1,SEARCH(",",A1)+1)+1,1))+NUMBERVALUE(MID(B1,SEARCH(",",B1,SEARCH(",",B1)+1)+1,1)) )&"product3"
```

Tested working in Excel mobile.
I hope you know what you're doing.

Comment: This isn't quite what they want, they have (at least) three fields per cell, they want to add up each field of the same type, and report all three back in the same cell again. Also this works okay with single digit numbers, but 10+ would fail.

Comment: @Jonno Yeah this is not complete yet. I was going to comment on the question but I guess I'll just ask in this reply. As said the text format must be the same for auto-fill to work, are you sure that all following rows have the same format: `0vanilla,1cola,5mango`? I could do a really long composite function that searches for commas but if the format is consistent I'll just hard-code character length, say pick a number and pick another number after 8 characters.

Comment: @Jonno I updated my answer but the problem remains: you must have all data fit in a single format. Like you said 10+ will fail. There is no looping or enumerating functions for Excel (without VBA) so dynamically choosing a pick-up range that fits your integer length is not possible. I would suggest: 1) add columns that have inventory number and number only, then add up these columns; or 2) revise the function and take digits into account every time when digit changes.

Comment: i tried the version2 formula, its showing error : "#Name?"

also the format will be same, but i have a lot of flavors. Not only three.
But the quantity wont be more than 9 for any flavors.
So can it be done?

Comment: @Nishkarsh Yes it can be done and I just updated my answer. The formula is becoming really really long and I hope you have experience with formulas. Do as I mentioned: replace `A1/B1` with cell references, and replace `product1/2/3` with product names. No spaces allowed between `,` and the next product name, same goes for original data.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's quicker not to do everything in Excel, I've found.
Not elegant, but often quicker overall.
For example, I'd just save this as a CSV file and load it into Notepad.
It's a cinch to just put a few more commas and/or new lines in, and re-save.
Then re-load the CSV into Excel, and the data is in columns and more manageable.